# urlEvent is undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, redirect, javascript-controller

We have below code being called from Cancel button on a Lightning component. We have used this lightning component on VF page.

```
navHome : function (component, event, helper) {

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "/home/home.jsp"
    });

    urlEvent.fire();

}
```

Above is throwing JS error,

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: CsApp:ConfigSettings$controller$navHome [urlEvent is
>   undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {CsApp:ConfigSettings$controller$navHome}

What should be the correct way to navigate Home page?

Comment: Did you add it as a dependency in the lightning app the the vf lightning out uses?

Comment: @Eric yes. Lightning Out used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm), this event is only supported in LEX and SF1, and not other technologies such as Lightning Out. In that case, just use window.location:

```
navHome : function (component, event, helper) {
    window.location = "/home/home.jsp";
}
```

If this component might be used in LEX, SF1, and other places, just check to see if urlEvent is undefined first:

```
navHome : function (component, event, helper) {

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    if(urlEvent) {
      urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "/home/home.jsp"
      });

      urlEvent.fire();
    } else {
      window.location = "/home/home.jsp"
    }
}
```

Comment: @sfdcfox - I use urlEvent in lightning out. Difference is I handle the navigation decision in the out function so the component does not have to worry. Not sure if it is better or not but

Comment: @Eric I was pretty sure there was an alternative method, but I wasn't sure how to wire that up. If you want to edit, feel free. I'd love to know more.

Answer (score 5):

Just a different way to slice the pie I guess but this puts the pieces where they belong IMHO and leave lightning in lightning and classic in classic

**Lightning App**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" description="exampleApp">
    <!-- Load the navigation events in the force namespace. -->
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

**VF Lightning Out**

```
    $Lightning.use("c:exampleApp", function () {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c.exampleComponent",
                {
                },
                "div_id",
                function (cmp) {
                    $A.eventService.addHandler({
                        event: 'force:navigateToURL',
                        handler: function (event) {
                            if (typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce.one) {
                                // VF page in S1 or Lightning Exp
                                // VF page in Classic
                                sforce.one.navigateToURL(event.getParams().url);

                            } else {
                                    window.parent.location.href = event.getParams().url;
                            }

                        }
                    });
                });
    });
```

**Controller Function**

```
functionName: function (component, event, helper) {
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": '/'
        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
```

Comment: Ah, that's cool. definitely going to remember that, we have a lot of projects that need doing.