# Force:Naviagte to Sobject in Lightning throwing exception in Lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have vf page:

```
  <apex:page standardController="case" extensions="Gss_CsHelathCheckExtension"  recordsetVar="lstAllUserData" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" />
<script>
var myList = {!lstSelUserDataIds}; 
$Lightning.use("c:GSS_CsHealthCheck", function(){
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:Gss_CaseHealthCheck",
        {caselist :myList},
        "lightning",
        function(cmp){
            $A.eventService.addHandler({
                event: 'force:navigateToObjectHome',
                handler: function(event) {
                    if (sforce && sforce.one) {
                        // VF page in S1 or Lightning Exp
                        sforce.one.navigateToObjectHome(event.$params$.scope);
                    } else {
                        // VF page in Classic
                        // Ugg! We need an if branch for each possible object type.
                        // Is there a better way of doing this?
                        if (event.$params$.scope === 'Case') {
                            window.location = '{!URLFOR($Action.Case.Tab, $ObjectType.Case)}';
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        });
});
</script>
```

GSS_CsHealthCheck

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
<aura:dependency resource="c:GSS_CaseHealthCheck"/>
  <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
 </aura:application>
```

GSS_CaseHealthCheck.CMP

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.CancelPage}" />
```

Js:

```
CancelPage:function(component,event,helper){ 
    //window.history.back();
    var event = $A.get('e.force:navigateToObjectHome');
    event.setParams({
        scope:'Case'
    });
    event.fire();
}
```

ERROR:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:GSS_CaseHealthCheck$controller$CancelPage [Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:GSS_CaseHealthCheck$controller$CancelPage}

I have refereed below post:

https://joebuschmann.com/salesforce-lightning-navigation-events-in-a-visualforce-page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your previous questions, you are surfacing this component in a Lightning Out Visualforce container. This is an important detail that significantly changes component support, behavior, and troubleshooting. Please include that information in your questions where it is relevant to ensure that valid solutions can be found.

When you are working in Lightning Out, it's important to check the [Lightning Component Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation) to find out whether or not the events and components you are using are supported in that context. In this case, you'll see under `force:navigateToSObject` that

> This event is handled by the `one.app` container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

Lightning Out is not part of the `one.app` container, even if your Visualforce page is being shown in Lightning Experience, and therefore does not support the event.

Comment: Duplicate of [urlEvent is undefined](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174279/urlevent-is-undefined/174437#174437)

Comment: Yes. simple solution will be passing current filter url to Lightning component & using window.location just redirect it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look here: https://joebuschmann.com/salesforce-lightning-navigation-events-in-a-visualforce-page/

Basically you need VF to have a custom handler for the event.

Comment: hi charles, remember to post the essentials of te  link, otherwise it might be flagged as a link only answer and deleted

Comment: I have updated the question and same problem. many people engagged to this question So I updated it.

Comment: Duplicate of [urlEvent is undefined](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174279/urlevent-is-undefined/174437#174437)